# Allowing two base URLs (same instance, same store)

Tags: magento2, admin, base-url

Is there any way to allow Magento to accept two base URLs?

The reason being our security team requested to disallow admin URL from being accessed from the internet so we are planning to use two URLs for internet vs intranet respectively. The admin URL will be blocked if accessed via the internet base URL and will only be allowed from the intranet base URL.

Since we are using Kubernetes with layers of Citrix loadbalancer, HAProxy and NGINX Ingress Controller in front, whitelisting based on IP pattern is not feasible without harassing the teams that manage all those layers. The only choice is to use Ingress to redirect the /admin/ path of the internet URL to some forbidden error page.

I have tried messing around with `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` but seems like those are for HTTP vs HTTPS only. Both our internet vs intranet URLs are using HTTPS due to security policy so we can't use those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two possible solutions, pick the one that best suits you :)

First one:

1. Configure the global base url as **admin.domain.com**. You can access the admin it with **admin.domain.com/admin**.
2. Change scope to the storeview, change the base url to **[www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)**

Second one:

1. Change the value  `Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Admin -> Admin Base URL -> Use Custom Admin URL` to Yes
2. Add the **admin.domain.com** to the **Custom Admin URL**

Comment: The first solution works for me. Thanks.